# Using Django SQL Explorer how do I correctly set default dates for paramters with PostgreSQL backend?

Tags: django, postgresql

Our Django application just migrated from MySQL to PostgreSQL, and we are in the process of updating our user queries to use the correct syntax.  These queries are stored/executed via [Django-SQL-Explorer.](https://github.com/groveco/django-sql-explorer)

I have a query that for simplicity's sake looks like this:

`SELECT * FROM table t WHERE t.scheduled_start_date BETWEEN $$from_date$$ AND $$to_date$$`

The query above works, but I would like to set defaults for today & today+30 respectively.

I've tried the following WHERE clauses to no avail:

#### Works with user entered date, default throws syntax error

`WHERE t.scheduled_start_date BETWEEN date('$$from_date:CURRENT_DATE$$') AND date('$$to_date:CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL \'30 DAY\'$$')`

**Error using defaults**:

`syntax error at or near "30" LINE 28: ...urrent_date') AND date('current_date + interval \'30 day\'') ^`

#### Defaults work correctly, but user entered dates do not:

`WHERE t.scheduled_start_date BETWEEN date($$from_date:CURRENT_DATE$$) AND date($$to_date:CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '30 DAY'$$)`

**Error with user dates**:

`function date(integer) does not exist LINE 28: WHERE t.scheduled_start_date BETWEEN date(2019-09-30) AND da... ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

The message about casting makes sense to me since the user enters in string data, however I can't seem to get the syntax right that casts to DATE but only when the default is overridden.

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You could use coalesce() expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately that also results in similar errors/functionality as above.  Ie, It will work for user values or default values, but not both.  I believe this is because the `$$from_date:CURRENT_DATE$$` is treated as a single value by Django SQL Explorer that then interpolates the values between the `$$` signs with either the default **or** the user values, so there is in effect nothing to coalesce.  I'd love to be wrong about that however, and just have messed up the syntax. :)

Comment: I thought of  `BETWEEN date(coalesce('$$from_date$$',current_date)) ...` This should work, assuming that your client passes a NULL value in cases where the user entered no data.

Comment: @clamp thanks for the suggestion, I got locked in to using the package syntax I didn't think of providing my own default values.  Unfortunately, that doesn't work as if no user data is present an empty string is returned, not NULL.  However, I'm playing with NULLIF now to see if I can get that working.  This doesn't work, but what I'm thinking is along these lines `BETWEEN date(coalesce(nullif('$$from_date$$',''),current_date))`

Comment: Of course, as soon as I comment that it doesn't work, I get it working.  Here's what I'm using now:  `BETWEEN date(coalesce(nullif('$$from_date$$',''),current_date::TEXT)) AND date(coalesce(nullif('$$to_date$$',''),(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '30 DAY')::TEXT))`
@clamp - if you want to post your suggestion as answer I'll accept it since it pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is a string value, `current_date` is a function call. The former needs quotes whereas the latter does not. Therefore your client side substitution will not work. You can move the default logic into the SQL statement using the `COALESCE()` function [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL).

In case the client sends NULL values for an empty user input this would result in the following where clause:

```
BETWEEN date(COALESCE('$$from_date$$',current_date)) 
    AND date(COALESCE('$$from_date$$',current_date + interval '30 DAYS'))
```

You added that your client sends an empty string, not a `NULL` value. So this should be changed to:

```
BETWEEN COALESCE(NULLIF('$$from_date$$','')::date, current_date)
    AND COALESCE(NULLIF('$$from_date$$','')::date, current_date + interval '30 DAYS')
```